# How do I fix the illegal configuration?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a .xib file and I want that to be a table view controller, but when I create a table view controller in the .xib file I get the error:

`Table views with embedded sections and cells are only supported in storyboard documents`.

How do I fix this?

Below is my code for the actual table view:

```
self.add = [Play(name: title!), Play(name: artist!), Play(name: album!)]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.add.count
    //return count of objects in array
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    var play: Play

    play = add[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = play.name
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Xibs are sort of out dated, and when they were invented, didn't have prototype cells that you could make in the Interface Builder.

When storyboards were introduced this functionality was made as well, except not back ported to the xib editor, so you can't use prototype cells in a xib unfortunately, you will need to make separate xibs for the cells layout.

Comment: I have a uiscroll view and 3 xib files to act like three different pages in one scroll view, but i want those pages to be uitables. What other solution could I go about?

Comment: This answer is not really correct. Xibs are not outdated. The problem is that a xib represents a view (`UIView`) while a storyboard represents a controller (`UIViewController`), therefore they have different use cases. You can create a reusable view with a xib but not with a storyboard. You can add controller related information (e.g. static table cells) to a storyboard but not to a xib.

Comment: yeah, out dated is the wrong term really, but tableviews dont have anything to do with viewcontrollers on their own, and you dont have to have a tableviewcontorller to use prototype cells, so there is no real reason that xibs shouldnt be able to do the same. I think the limitation comes from how you get views out of xibs, each view is an element in the xib, if you have prototype cells, how does that fit into it? it would mean quite a drastic change to the xibs api, hence they cant add that functionality back into the xib that they have in the storyboard. just speculation really